# Web.Config encoding problems

Tags: c#, asp.net, encoding

Wanted to let you know that I've tried to solve my problem before turning to the community for help.

I need to send a request with a couple of query parameters to a web service from which I should get an XML in the response which I need to parse and populate image source and image link with the values.

let's assume the the url for the website is:

domain.com/user=1&passwd=2&param=u

When i type this in a browser I could see the XML i should get as a response.

I place the value in appSettings in a web.Config file like so:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="GetImageUrl" value="http://domain.com/user=1&passwd=2&param=u"/>
</appSettings>
```

However, this would not compile because the compiler cannot understand '&' so I used the encoded version like this:

```
<appSettings>
     <add key="GetImageUrl" value="http://domain.com/user=1&amp;passwd=2&amp;param=u"/>
</appSettings>
```

However, when I type this I see the XML with "Error" values which is one of the expected values to be returned if wrong parameters are sent.

How should I proceed?

Thank you very much!

---

Edit:

Wanted to let you know that I've also tried "&;amp;" and "%26"

Answer (score 4):

The `web.config` file is an XML file, so you *must* encode `&` as `&amp;`.

When reading the value in your program, you will get a `&`.

I don't know wha tyou mean by:

> when I type this I see the XML with "Error" values which is one of the expected values to be returned if wrong parameters are sent

Where is this happening? Sending where?

Comment: When I type "http://domain.com/user=1&amp;passwd=2&amp;param=u" in the browser I can see the correct XML structure but the elements that should contain the values have a value of 'Error'.

Comment: @Johancho - When your .NET application parses the `web.config` file, the `&amp;` will turn to `&`.